# MQ Tables in Toad Package Viewer

Tags: plsql, db2, toad

What is MQ Tables in DB2 package viewer using Toad editor?

Screenshot as attached:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[IBM says](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/apsg/src/tpc/db2z_db2mqtables.html)

> The DB2® MQ tables contain service and policy definitions that are used by the Message Queue Interface (MQI) based DB2 MQ functions. You must populate the DB2 MQ tables before you can use these MQI-based functions.

Comment: What Db2 version/platform are you using